# Pressure difference inside a moving flowing fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

In a moving fluid how does velocity difference cause pressure difference?

Comment: It is pressure difference that causes fluid motion.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure adjusts the velocity to ensure mass conservation at a point.